# block_html_id for view comes with uuid drupal

Tags: views

I am not sure but to my understanding the block_html_id for the views should be with the patter of block-views-NAME-OF-VIEW-MACHINE-NAME, however it is coming up as block-views-UUID...i am guessing it is uuid some kind bunch of letters and numbers. Is this a bug? or this can be configured. The problem with the block-views-UUID pattern is that i am unable to use it in the preprocessor functions such as THEME-preprocess-block()

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Env: Drupal 7.26, views 7.x-3.7

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the following:
[Views Block's machine name is being "hashed" (?)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14406/views-blocks-machine-name-is-being-hashed?rq=1)

It hashes block view name if the view name is larger than 32 chars