# Naming conventions for fields machine name in Drupal

Tags: entities

There is a naming convention for the fields machine name such as:

```
entity_name_field_name
```

for not shared fields

or

```
field_name
```

for shared fields.

When I go to start a project, what should be the naming convention I must use on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your entity is resuable (like say apart of a Feature) I typically name my fields as "field_PROJECTNAME_SOMETHING_DESCRIPTIVE" that fits within the 25-ish character limit for field names.

If I put the content type into a Feature then yes I use a consist naming pattern for all fields. If I have a Feature for a content type called DIET (short for Digital Identity) I can make a field called `field_diet_presidential_number`.

For example I'm working on a project I call internally the "Presidency Project". I may name my fields with a prefix of `prez`. This is true for anything that requires a `machine_name`. This way when making Features or exporting code I can at a glance see some piece of configuration that is *project specific* and I know to export it somehow.

Machine names should at the least be globally distinguisable from Core fields and other configuration values (such as system variables, and Pattern machine names, Rule machine names, etc).

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/field/field.module?h=7.x#n65), the maximum length of a field name is 32 characters.

Comment: @skwashd Sure,although my reply included discussion of "machine names" and not all machine related names (entity names, views display names, rules names, etc) are limited to 32 characters. For example, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14406/views-blocks-machine-name-is-being-hashed

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR Always use a short succinct but entity agnostic machine name for your fields because requirements will change.

I would never put the entity name in the field name. While today you might think that a field will only ever be used on a node. Requirements change over time. Today's assumptions will bite you tomorrow.

For example you might have a *"Hero image"* field and decide to use "node_hero_image" (or worse "node_blog_hero_image") because it is only used for nodes.  Later someone decides that they want to use hero images on another entity type - say taxonomy terms to create nice "category landing pages".  You have hard coded the entity type into the field. You have 2 choices, either keep the poorly named field or create a new one - both options are less than idea an increase the technical debt in your project.

If you had've used "hero" as the machine name for your field it would remain flexible. The purpose of the field is clear to anyone who sees it in the UI. You don't need "_image" in the name either as most places in the UI will tell you it is an image field.

Comment: What is the meaning of "TL;DR" ?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer TL;DR is "too long, don't read" ...

Comment: Actually, it's "Too long, *didn't* read" (subtle but important difference). It is a presumption by the writer the reader might find the explanation too long to read. It's *not* a recommendation by the writer it should not be read :) The origin is actually that it might be used by a commenter, meaning they found something too long to read.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the (illuminating) article "[Relativity Model for Drupal](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/overview)", especially the related page about "[Wrapping Information Architecture and Documentation](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/wrapping-information-architecture-and-documentation)". Here is a quote from it:

> To create an Event content type in Drupal is a simple task. But there's a nuance to that task that is overlooked very often. That nuance is the machine name. But why is the machine name of a content type such an important step?
>
> - It gives the content type an explicit name of your choosing and allows database indexing to act on that machine name while being queried.
> - All fields contained within that content type will share the same machine name before the field name. This allows the Views module to clearly gather field data in a very defined manner using the indexed machine name.
> - Fields that are entity references out to other content types also begin with the same machine name followed by their own machine name. This allows simple and visual identification for origination and destination of data relationship.

It also contains an interesting example of what seems to be a great naming convention.

Comment: thanks Pierre I will read all the article, I think that the machine name is very important in large projects and in the use of the module features . Thanks a lot

Comment: Too weird that the article doesn't exists anymore, maybe it was only an assumption? Therefore the article was erased?

Answer (score 1):

There is no generally accepted convention as far as I am aware, but clearly it makes very good sense to develop some internal standards within your project or company.

The *field_* prefix is, in my opinion, not necessary nor useful. It's a legacy from Drupal 6's CCK module, which was the forerunner of Drupal 7's *field* subsystem. Although that prefix is included by default when creating fields via the standard core UI, that behaviour can be changed, for example with this module: [Remove field name prefix](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_name_prefix_remove)

It would probably make sense to use a short initial prefix that you can expect to be unique, to help avoid possible conflicts with field ids or database table names used by other modules. I often use a prefix of *ng_* which is short for my own [domain name](http://netgenius.co.uk) and so *hopefully* won't be used by anybody else. Of course, this does not *guarantee* that there will be no conflicts, but it helps.

If you are developing a Drupal module or distribution for general use, then using a short initial prefix representing the name of that module or distribution would make sense, again to help avoid name conflicts with other modules. This is very common practice for naming PHP functions within module and theme code, where the full project name of the module or theme is usually used as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I use one of those options:

1. field_type_function#

> field_img_heroimage1
>
> field_img_figure1
>
> field_img_icon1
>
> field_longtext_details1
>
> field_longtext_details_exp1
>
> field_longtext_details2
>
> ...

2. field_type#

> field_img1
>
> field_img2
>
> field_img3
>
> field_longtext1
>
> field_longtext2
>
> field_longtext3
>
> ...

Also you could add the project name before the type: field_projectname_type# .
I don't recommend to put the entity name in the field name like skwashd said.