# How to show user info in DIV based on link click?

Tags: views, blocks, users, javascript

I'm currently trying to make a 'biography' block with Drupal profile pictures and when you click on them more information (user fields that has been filled in by the Drupal user) will dynamically display in a block. To be more specific, this is what I want:

[https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/change-content-in-div-based-on-link-click](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/change-content-in-div-based-on-link-click/)

I tried to make a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) block displaying the profile pictures. These pictures will function as thumbnails. The things is, I have no idea how it will show more information when you click on them (without going to the profile page). Is there a Views trick, Jquery way or any other method I can try?

Comment: The "link-click" aspect is definitely jQuery, so you will need to find a code snippet or plugin that does exactly what you want and 1. [Load the jQuery into your theme](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/71796/28700); 2. In Views, [rewrite the HTML output](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29842/28700) according to the requirements of the plugin.

Comment: You could try the colorbox module.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> Colorbox is a light-weight customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery. This module allows for integration of Colorbox into Drupal.
>
> Images, iframed or inline content etc. can be displayed in a overlay above the current page.
>
> Features
>
> - Works as a Formatter in entities and in views.
> - Excellent integration with core image field and image styles and the Insert module
> - Choose between a default style and a number of other styles that are included.
> - Style the Colorbox with a custom Colorbox style in your theme.
> - Drush command, drush colorbox-plugin, to download and install the Colorbox plugin in sites/all/libraries.

**Credits**: [rooby](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/10729/rooby) (in a comment below the question).