# Modify HTML Output of A View?

Tags: 7, views

So I have setup a View as a Block that echoes out three products from Commerce. However I want each of the items to be formatted in this way:

```
<a class="dhover" href="#">
<div class="col33">
<p class="amount">PRODUCT PRICE</p>
<p class="desc">PRODUCT DESCRIPTION<br><br>Donate Now ></p>
</div>
</a>
```

Is it possible to edit the formatting specifically in this way?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can format your views output as you required by creating a template file for it. for further information check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/create-template-file-for-views-block

Comment: Use Rewrite Results Option in View Fields ....

Answer (score 1):

You can make the same with [semantic views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews), it let you to choose what hmtl tag wants for every field, and also what class/id you want to use.

also, without programing,

I leave enable the link.

I dont't output the amount.

But in the 3º element, I will rewrite the ouput and add the [amount-token] So you can build the div you need also.

all this without use tpl.

anyway the best option always will be to make make as say the first comment.