# How do I move more link to title of views block?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I am using Drupal 7 and Views, I created a block and a "more link" for showing on the frontpage.

How can I move the "more link" next to the title of views block?

[image: Mockup for the views block output]

Answer (score 2):

You should copy the [views-view.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view.tpl.php/7) from views module into your theme folder. If you want to do this only for a specific views, you should also rename the file like `views-view--your-view.tpl.php`. Then you can simply move the 'more link' part wherever you like in this template file.

UPDATE:
Thanks to @Mołot's pointing about an issue that the title is rendered by the block, I've found out that there is already a discussion about that in the API page. As a workaround, you can set in the block configuration the title to `<none>` so that it isn't rendered by block. And in the views template replace the following part which is responsible for printing title:

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
  <?php print $title; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php if (empty($title)): ?>
  <?php $title = check_plain($view->get_title()); ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php print $title; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Aren't the blocks' titles defined at a bit higher levels that views' ones?

Comment: @Mołot if you look at the source code in the API page for [views-view.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view.tpl.php/7) you would see that both `$title` and `$more` variables printed in the same file.

Comment: So what? I just tested it and first line of views-view--test--block.tpl.php appears AFTER `<h2 class="block-title">test</h2>` in markup. Block's display renders title first, and then hides it so views' template doesn't.

Comment: I didn't test it, just looked at the API page. But it seems there's already an issue about that, at least the comments at the same API page arguing about this: https://api.drupal.org/comment/44378#comment-44378

Comment: I did test. Process in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing about the issue.  I didn't also know that. But I'm still thinking that the best way to implement this, is to make the title printed by the views template not the block. So I'll update my answer with a workaround which is also mentioned in the discussion/comments on the API page of the views-view.tpl.php.

Comment: Thanks. I like to see many valid answers to one question ;) Just don't duplicate answer by Alfred Armstrong.

Comment: Hmm, I think @Alfred Armstrong has already mentioned about printing the `$view->title` instead of the `$title` variable. If you think this is a duplicate answer, I can delete my answer.

Comment: He didn't mention filter_xss_admin at all, yours is more comprehensive as for now. I still think moving more and leaving all block markup in one tpl is better, but oh well :P viva la choice!

Comment: :) I am also for one tpl, like moving the title to views tpl, instead of moving the 'more link' to block tpl. Viva la choice ;)

Comment: By the way, why filter_xss_admin and not [check_plain](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) ?

Comment: @Mołot For no specific reason. check_plain is also ok. Actually thinking that it doesn't make much sense to have markup in views title, so check_plain would be enough. I'll update my answer again :)

Answer (score 2):

**If you don't want the process, just result, scroll to TL;DR below!**

In your view setting page, go to display of your block. In it, expand *Advanced* column, and on the bottom click *Theme: Information*. You will get screen like this:

[image: Theme Information screen]

Here you can see selection of names. You don't want to override *views-view.tpl.php* as it's default for all views and all displays. You want it for blocks, so *views-view--block.tpl.php* is a natural choice for all blocks, and *views-view--test--block.tpl.php* if you only want to affect view named *test*.

Create an empty file with selected name, click "Display output" link, copy what you see there into your file, save, and upload to your theme directory. Then, click *Rescan template files* - now your new template is in use and can be edited.

Problem is that block's title is not rendered in it. The part

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
  <?php print $title; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

is not executed as title was already rendered by *block.tpl.php* of your template, probably something like this:

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>
<?php endif;?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

Similar, yes, but *block.tpl.php* cannot know about your `$more`. Trying to import it with `global $more` causes:

> Notice: Undefined variable: more

So what do we have defined? Time to

```
<?php dpr(get_defined_vars()); ?>
```

Sadly, no luck here. So maybe we should force our theme to use view's tpl directly for blocks? In [`theme_preprocess_block(&$variables, $hook)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7) temporarily add `dpr($variables['block_html_id']);`. Now, I see my block's id is *block-views-test-block-1*, so in the hook I add:

```
if ($variables['block_html_id'] == 'block-views-test-block-1') {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'views_view__test__block';
}
```

Note that `-` and `_` are swapped between suggestion and file name. But that will not work - it will execute our tpl in a context where it has no variables. What's now? I add a bare block template, of course:

```
if ($variables['block_html_id'] == 'block-views-test-block-1') {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__raw';
}
```

With only one line in it:

```
<?php print $content ?>
```

Now the title is not printed using main *block.tpl.php*, so in your *views-view--block.tpl.php* you can move following section around:

But wait, $title is **NOT** available inside view's block template, now you can have more within the title area, but title itself is not there. So time to rollback template suggestion.

**TL;DR**

From your *views-view--block.tpl.php* remove lines that print `$more`. At the beginning, add:

```
global $block_more;
$block_more = $more;
```

In your main *block.tpl.php*, use something like:

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?>
  <?php global $block_more; ?>
  <?php if (@$block_more): ?>
    <?php print $block_more; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </h2>
<?php endif;?>
```

The rest is a matter of CSS.

Comment: If you have more than one view block on a page, this will almost certainly break. Both blocks will point to the same page on their more link (whichever was processed last.) You should not use globals to pass information around. It's not good practice.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong only if all views - related templates are processed before block related ones and as far as I tested that's not the case. From your comments it seems you didn't test? I'm open to admit my mistake in testing if you will care and actually test your statement. And Drupal uses globals all the time. In a perfect world we would have unrendered view object accessible in block.tpl.php, but since we don't (we'll see how it will look like in 8), we need to get along somehow. I don't claim my answer is the best. I tried to provide as much background as possible for readers to decide.

Comment: No, I didn't test. But did your testing include block or views caching? I'd be interested to see how that pans out. Even if it works this is not a good example for others to follow. Use drupal_static if you want globally accessible data. That's the preferred way.

Comment: Want another reason not to use globals? Automated testing will break.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to customise both the views block template (the inner part of the HTML) and the block template for the view or views in general (the outer part). So you might have a views block template as per [Create template file for views block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/create-template-file-for-views-block) and also a block template block--views.tpl.php in your theme.

Thus you can amend your views template so it renders the title from $view->get_title() instead of the $title variable (which will be blank), and put the more link after it. At the same time you would amend the block template so it doesn't show the title at all.

But a pure CSS solution may work just as well.