# How to remove default div of views block?

Tags: views

My html code:

```
<div class="workList col-lg-4">
  <div class="view-back">
    <a href="" target="_blank">&rarr;</a>
  </div>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php print base_path(). path_to_theme();?>/assets/images/img.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

In views-view-fields--name--name.tpl I'm using this code:

```
<div class="view-back">
    <a href="" target="_blank">&rarr;</a>
</div>
<?php print $fields['field_fieldName']->content;?>
```

The generated output is the following.

```
<div class="col-lg-4  first odd">
      <div class="view-back">
    <a href="" target="_blank">→</a>
</div>
<div>## I have to remove this div
  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/Drupal/name/sites/default/files/styles/recent_work/public/img.jpg?itok=vVkU2WWt" width="390" height="250" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

I have to remove the default `<div>` before the `<img>` tag.

Comment: use Java Script to remove this div instead of create new view template file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create template file for views block](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/create-template-file-for-views-block)

Comment: For anyone reading - do not use Javascript to do this. Override the default view template to remove the wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

Click on field and edit settings
Override style settings for field

Customize field HTML
Customize field and label HTML

Comment: @ gfarishyan Thank you. Actually there is not printing an image. I am using <?php print $fields['field_fieldName']->content;?> Am I wrong??

Comment: what is the output of print_r($fields['field_fieldName']) or even use dsm/dpm dpr if you enabled devel module ?