# Is there a way to make a unique view template for a specific type of view?

Tags: views, theming

I needed to edit the views-view-unformatted.tpl.php for a specific view, however I'd rather it not apply to every view. Is there a possible way to make a unique view template to select from? Rather than rewriting every view that uses views-view-unformatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Open the Views Admin UI and in Theme Information there is a list of available template files

[image]

For example in my website it is:

[image]

You can use any of them.

Comment: But editing those templates would have me run into the same problem. Any view that used those templates would be overwritten. I'm wondering if it's possible to make a template unique to one specific view.

Comment: Not at all, As an example `views-view--library-block.tpl.php` is a template file for every block of `library` view or `views-view--library-block-1.tpl.php` is a template file for a display block with machine name `block_1`

Answer (score 1):

You can copy 1 of the default templates provided by views (the source code is in the /views folder) into a template file named specifically for that 1 view.

This is explained in this other answer:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/11472/3279